# Print image from Android

Tags: android, printing

Is there some way to connect via IP from Android to a printer?

I need to print an image from my app, and I don't want to search any print service on my network using the network service discovery because I know the printer's IP address and I want to connect with it directly.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a Socket instance for that provided you know the used port too.

Comment: Once I have a Socket, how can I print a bitmap with it?

Comment: Sorry but i have no idea. Thats because i never googled for it. Seems i'm not alone.

Comment: You can print using socket connection
Do you find a solution for print image via socket ?

Comment: I've printed via socket, but with this method I can use a print operation passing a String, but not a Bitmap. If is mposible send a Bitmap via socket, I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: print bitmap using socket did you find any solution ? @rlopezo

Comment: Hi @MuhammadAsad, it's been a long time since I asked this, I don't remember clearly but I think that finally I installed some printer service in the device in order to find the printer when I needed to print. Sorry if the explanation is poor but I haven't programmed anything for android for years hehe.